# Wired IR with CIRT1/2 for Calypso CA-1000

Tags: wiring, lirc

Is it possible to do IR over wire with a Calypso CA-1000 amp?
It has an IR receiver and wired IR in/out ports (IR out for daisy-chaining) and looks for CIRT1, 2, and custom codes.

I would like to be able to control 4 of these from a web interface, but that is for another time.

Comment: I would be using a Raspberry Pi.  Would LIRC be able to do this?